# I'm not able to import 450 .sql.zip file in mysql phpmyadmin on live server

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql

Actually I have magento database back and I import database back from magento tools -> database back up in .sql.gz file and I extract .sql.gz file into .sql file then again compress into .sql.zip file and try to import in database without any success yet, .sql.zip have size 500MB. How can I import that file in a live MySQL server using phpMyAamin.

1. I tried `bigdump`: actually it imports data but not all data is import data in just half mb.
2. I set my `php.ini` setting

   > memory_limit = 500MB
   >
   > max_execution_time = 3600
   >
   > post_max_size = 500MB
   >
   > upload_max_filesize = 500MB
3. When I tried to import file it processes the import database at least 10-20 minutes after that page stopped processing and got blank page with server not found.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your uncompressed sql files are larger than 500mb, so phpmyadmin might fail on the memory limit (not sure).

However, if possible, I would strongly recommend not to use phpmyadmin for such large files, but a direct mysql command such as :

```
zcat /path/to/backup.sql.gz | mysql -u 'root' -p 'password' your_database
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend not to use phpmyadmin _at all_ :).

Comment: Yes, Increasing the limits is no solution. Use MySQL command for large SQL imports.